# How to compare if an HTML element exists in the node array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nodes

selectedContentWrap: HTML nodes.
htmlVarTag: is an string.

How do I check if the HTML element exists in the nodes?

The htmlVarTag is a string and don't understand how to convert it so it check again if there is a tag like that so that if there is I can remove it?

here is output of my nodes  that is stored in selectedContentWrap
[image]

```
 var checkingElement = $scope.checkIfHTMLinside(selectedContentWrap,htmlVarTag );
 $scope.checkIfHTMLinside = function(selectedContentWrap,htmlVarTag){

     var node = htmlVarTag.parentNode;
     while (node != null) {
         if (node == selectedContentWrap) {
             return true;
         }
         node = node.parentNode;
     }
     return false;


 }
```

Comment: Charlieftl, I had replied with answear below with what my object was

Comment: still a mish-mash of conflict about removing vs testing for existence....overall question is poorly written and is not absolute...see [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you could paste the content of `selectedContentWrap` I would be able to test this code, but I think this would work

```
// Code goes here

var checkIfHTMLinside = function(selectedContentWrap,htmlVarTag){
  for (item of selectedContentWrap) {
    if (item.nodeName.toLowerCase() == htmlVarTag.toLowerCase()){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ologho Cyril Paul, 
I tested you code, but looks to me you got an spelling error . Didn't you mean innerHtml.indexOf ? You are missing the "x" ? I also get an error Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

Simplest is use [`angular.element`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) which is a subset of jQuery compatible methods

```
$scope.checkIfHTMLinside = function(selectedContentWrap,htmlVarTag){
   // use filter() on array and return filtered array length as boolean
   return selectedContentWrap.filter(function(str){
      // return length of tag collection found as boolean
      return angular.element('<div>').append(str).find(htmlVarTag).length
   }).length;    
});
```

Still not 100% clear if objective is only to look for a specific tag or any tags (ie differentiate from text only)

Or as casually mentioned to actually remove the tag

If you want to remove the tag it's not clear if you simply want to unwrap it or remove it's content also ... both easily achieved using `angular.element`

Answer (score 0):

Try using: `node.innerHTML` and checking against that

Answer (score 0):

is it me or post a question on stackoverflow and 20min after test testing I figure it.,...

the answer is that in the  selectedContentWrap I already got list of nodes, all I need to do i compare , so a simple if for loop will fit.

To compare the names  I just need to use .nodeName as that works cross browser ( correct me if I am wrong)

Some dev say that "dictionary of tag names and anonymous closures instead" - but couldn't find anything. If anyone has this library could you please post it to the question?

here is my code.

```
  var node = selectedContentWrap;
      console.log('node that is selectedwrapper', selectedContentWrap)
      for (var i = 0; i < selectedContentWrap.length; i++) {
          console.log('tag name is ',selectedContentWrap[i].nodeName);
          var temptagname = selectedContentWrap[i].nodeName; // for debugging
          if(selectedContentWrap[i].nodeName == 'B' ){
              console.log('contains element B');
          }

      }
```

Comment: This would work, what if a node in the array has children nodes which actually contain the tag you looking for?

Comment: I got other function that looks  for HTML tag inbetween content and puts them all in an array called selectedContentWrap. So if it would have children, children, it would put in the array selectedContentWrap.